# Can't figure out how to get rid of white background

Tags: html, css

So I have made a navbar with a few buttons on it, and the main issue im running into now is that every time I hover my mouse over the buttons, there is a white box that surrounds it.

Heres the link to my [Code](https://codepen.io/AlexVeringa/pen/YLKppb?editors=1100).

```
<div id="navigationBar">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="navbar-custom" id="vmanCoding">
  <a class="brand-name" href="#"><button type="button">vMan Coding</button>
</a>
</div>
<div class="btn-custom">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#"><button type="button" id="about">About</button></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><button type="button" id="portfolio">Portfolio</button>
</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><button type="button" id="contact">Contact</button></a>
</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: In 
.nav > li > a { Remove the padding, by setting the padding:0; that worked for me.

Comment: It is from bootstrap default nav. You can override like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxNGwB?editors=1100)

Comment: The background color applied from default bootstrap CSS. to override update the following CSS in your custom code .nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover { background-color: transparent;}

Answer (score 1):

Heres the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aGoLLa?editors=1100)

As the background color is applied by default bootstrap CSS.
You need to override the `background-color` from your custom code

```
.btn-custom .nav li a:hover { 
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this in your css:

```
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover { background-color: transparent; }
```